# I want to open a Specific Chrome Profile using Selenium & Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I want to use A Specific Chrome Profile which I made for "A University Project" (Include some Default Accounts).
I searched a lot on stack overflow & Selenium official documentation but I'm not able to find a way.

**This is My Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 2")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\new\Videos\microsoft-teams-class-attender-main\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")
```

> After running this I got the same new "Temporary Profile", which selenium always use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `options = Options()` or `options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()` in place of `options = webdriver.ChromeOptions`.

Otherwise, you are pointing at an object (namely `webdriver.ChromeOptions`), and not making an instance of that object by including the needed parentheses

Comment: This is nothing to do with, What i asked..!!